# SharePoint 2010 - Checkboxes (allow multiple selection) results

Tags: html, sharepoint, workflow

I have a list set up with a few choice columns that allow multiple results and with the workflow I am adding each result to a string variable if the columns are not null.  I then change the result to "choices, comma delimited" within the workflow.

Looking to see if there is a way to get a space after the separating comma to use in an HTML table within the email body.  Currently, results are displayed as;

value,value,value

Looking for the output to be;

value, value, value

This way the table will break at the space after the comma vs. thinking its a long text string and not allowing breaks to occur.

Thanks!